# Spring WebFlux switchIfEmpty to return different type

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getMessage(ServerRequest request) {
    //this call returns Mono<ApiClientResponse>
    return apiClient.hystrixWrappedGetMessages(request.headers().asHttpHeaders(), request.queryParams())
            .switchIfEmpty(/* Here */)
}
```

Excuse the slightly incomplete code, I was restructuring it when I ran into this problem. The gist is that where it says /* Here */ in the `switchIfEmpty()` call, the compiler is forcing a type of `Mono<ApiClientResponse>`, but when `hystrixWrappedGetMessages()` returns `Mono.empty()` I want to handle that by returning a 204 `Mono<ServerResponse>` for example, otherwise I want to return a 200. How can I accomplish that?

Ideally I could check if it was Mono.empty() in a map call, but it doesn't seem to enter map if it's an empty Mono. Thought about using optionals but they don't seem to play nicely with Monos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to `flatMap` your response if good, and if an `Mono#empty` is returned the `flatMap` will get ignored.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> getMessage(ServerRequest request) {
    return apiClient.hystrixWrappedGetMessages(request.headers().asHttpHeaders(), request.queryParams())
        .flatMap(response -> {
            // Do your processing here
            return ServerResponse.ok().body( .... );
        }.switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.noContent());
}
```

Comment: Ah, I think what I was missing from my understanding was how it falls through the chain. Thanks for the answer